# Workflow in existing WCF

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation

I have an existing WCF service.

Is it possible to add operation contract to the service interface and have the implementation in a workflow?

Or I absolutly need a seperate service interface for my workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you publish a WCF service you are publishing the interface and telling it what implementation to use. You can specify only one implementation, otherwise how would WCF know where to route which request. So in short you need to use a separate interface for your workflow services. That said, if you don't want to change your public facing API there is no reason you can't create a minimal implementation that just passes request on to your worklflow service.